# C# XmlWriter Syntax To Write Multiple Namespace Tags

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

I am attempting to write the following line with C#'s XmlWriter.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
```

I seem to only seem have an option to write on xmlns (and then with no :suffix), when using the xmlWriter.WriteStartElement method.

Is it possible to do with XmlWriter?

Comment: have you tried XmlWriter.WriteStartElement Method (String, String, String) ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.    Attribute 1 looks for a "prefix" which gets added before the element name and after the xmlns:    This obviously doesn't work.   Nor does it allow you to specify two xmlns attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?  Adjusted to use LookupPrefix.

```
writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
writer.WriteStartElement("configuration");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "patch", null, "http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "set", null, "http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

outputs:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" />
```

Comment: But since both need to be preceded by xmlns: that wouldn't work.   I would end up with <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xmlns="namespace" />   which obviously won't work, since that last "xmlns" should say "set" instead.  Oh yeah, and the second one's value should be another URL.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Tweeked it a bit. looking up the prefix seems to function better.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the requirement for xmlns, seems closer though.